# javascript Image tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm adding an image snapshot of a webcam to a div using jquery (2.1.3)

Why does this not work:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + data;
image.width = "320px";
image.height = "240px";
$("#video").html(image);
```

The image tag has sizes 0 for w and h;

This does work

```
var image = $("<img>", {
    "src": "data:image/jpg;base64," + data,
    "width": "640px", "height": "480px"});
$("#video").html(image);
```

Comment: `.html()` expects a string as input, and inserts that string as if it was an html snippet into the dom at the specified point. You're not passing in a string. You're passing in an Image object, which is NOT going to work. jquery happens to be extending the image object with a .toString magic method which happens to spit out an html representation of the image object. so version 1: image object, not work. version 2: jquery object, works.

Comment: @MarcB nope, you can't be more wrong, `html()` can handle elements, text and jquery object, this is not the problem, @Fenrir can you provide fiddle of your code?

Comment: @neo: http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function   the only acceptable parameter is an htmlstring... no parameter = return .innerhtml instead.

Comment: @MarcB -- http://jsfiddle.net/ufd55x08/ - `.html()` works fine with a Jquery object as the param.

Comment: @tymeJV: which is what I said. the second code sample works because it's a jquery object going in.

Comment: the problem is with the `px`, you either should use `image.width="320"` or `image.style.width="320px"` and there is no problem with `.html()`, cheers

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that a pure HTML `Image` element takes numbers as its `width` and `height`, not dimensions,  so remove the "px":

```js
var image = new Image();
image.src = "https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
image.width = "320";
image.height = "240";
$("#video").html(image);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="video"></div>
```

JQuery is smarter and converts the `width` and `height` properties to set `style="width:320px; height:240px"`, i.e. using css, which is preferred as `width` and `height` attributes are deprecated.